# Error connect oracle database with node

Tags: node.js, oracle11g, centos

i have problem with 'node-oracledb' library.its a simple file which try to connect to the local database.
the environment : centos 6.4 / nodejs v0.12.2 / the oracle library node-oracledb 0.3.8
 environment variables from .bash_profile:

> export ORACLE_BASE=/usr/oracle/app export ORACLE_SID=orcl export
>   ORACLE_HOME=/usr/oracle/app/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1 export
>   OCI_LIB_DIR=$ORACLE_HOME/lib export
>   OCI_INC_DIR=$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/public
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
var oracle = require('oracle');

    var connectData = {
        hostname: "localhost",
        port: 1521,
        database: "orcl", // System ID (SID)
        user: "scott",
        password: "oracle"
                 }
```

errors:
    .Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/oracle_bindings'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object. (/usr/oracle/dev/atlantisSGBD/node_modules/oracle/lib/oracle.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the unmaintained [`oracle` module](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle). You might consider switching to Oracle's [`oracledb` module](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) instead.

If that's not a viable solution: The module it is having trouble finding (`oracle_bindings`) appears to be installed via gyp in the installation process for `oracle`. So try installing it again and take special note if that piece succeeds or not.

Moreover, note that [the installation instructions for `oracle`](https://github.com/joeferner/node-oracle/blob/master/INSTALL.md) are more extensive than the typical Node.js module. Make sure you have all the environment variables set that it requires and that they are set to the correct values. (In your code, check the values in the `process.env` object.) Make sure you have successfully installed everything the instructions require you to have installed.